# Modifying a SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS created from a SQL Server 2000 DTS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, dts

We are looking to migrate our SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008 and then eventually up to SQL Server 2012.

One of my tasks is to look into migrating our old DTS packages.

I used the wizard, imported a very simple DTS package and converted it to SSIS.

I see this SSIS package in the SQL Server Management Studio and can schedule it as a job.

I would like to view the details of this new Package in the BI developer.

so I export the new Package to file system, Start a new project in BI and add this package as an existing item.

The BI won't display the package though, it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

So have I done something wrong? am I missing a step? or is there an easier way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

This was My own Fault, I forgot to Select Integration Services Connection Project when selecting the new project.